# Is the category of Stone spaces monoidal?

Tags: category-theory

Is there a monoidal structure on the category of compact Hausdorff totally disconnected topological spaces (i.e. Stone spaces)?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, the product of two Stone spaces is again a Stone space, and places a monoidal structure on the category of Stone spaces.

Comment: Oh, thanks. (You are saying that it is a "cartesian" monoidal category then, right?)

Comment: Yes, if the monoid product is given by the ordinary product then it is called a cartesian monoidal category.